# Trying to print paragraphs in div line by line while giving content limit to characters in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, limit, paragraph

Hi am trying to print the paragraphs line by line in div when content in div is given limit of 15 characters but its printing all paragraphs side by side how can I print line by line . Here is my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div").text(function(index,currentText) {
        return currentText.substr(0, 15);
      });
    });

   <?php
         echo "<div>";
         for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
             $key=array('helloss','howaree','welcomes','whkkky','getkkk');
             $random_key= array_rand($keywords); 
             $keys ="<p>" . $key[$random_key]  . $key[$random_key] . "</p>";
             echo $keys; 
           }
             echo "</div>";
  ?>
```

Suppose it the 15 characters in `div` are

```
   hellosshowaree
   h
```

It should be shown as above as only 15 characters should be present in `div` but its shown as below

```
 hellosshowareeh
```

Comment: `hellosshowareeh` is 15 characters ... not sure I understand ... can you post the HTML as it appears in the browser

Comment: You can put a line-break using `<br />` after each `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your Javascript coding as follows

```
 var myDiv = $('#your-div-id');
 myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,16))
```

Comment: but that would be 16 characters - OP wants 15 - and his divs don't have an id

Comment: its combining all pragraphs together side by side

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt= $('div').text();
if(txt.length > 15)
 $('div').text(txt.substring(0,15));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return currentText.substr(0, 14);
```

User the range 0 to 14 as these are 15 characters.
Using 0 to 15 makes it 16 characters which is why that extra h is included in the string.
I guess this is it.